# How do I select multiple files when clicking on the FileUpload Browse button in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dom-events

I want to be able to select multiple files when I click browse on the FileUpload browse button.  I have it now to where I can choose one file and add it as a list using a jQuery but would I would like is to select multiple files to be added when I click open.  Is there a simple way of doing this and is there maybe some kind of Javascript that might be able to handle this event?

Comment: Have you looked at the following? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254831/asp-net-free-ajax-file-upload-control http://forums.asp.net/t/1332463.aspx http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-multiple-file-uploads-in-aspnet-2

Answer (score 0):

Try in this [way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68374/Upload-Multiple-Files-in-ASP-NET-using-jQuery) or look thought payment component [there](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/upload.aspx) or [there](http://www.mediachase.com/fuploader/examples.aspx) or [there](http://ajaxuploader.com/)

Comment: There is not an easier solution?  I know the AJAX Uploader will work but it is only a trial.  There is no javascript code to handle this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing easy.  Because the file selector is part of Windows itself, you will have to use something built on a framework that is installed (i.e. Flash, Silverlight, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so soon.

Comment: By any chance do you know how to use the AJAX Uploader as far as an example.

Comment: I've tried to do it so in early version of visual studio but without success , so this can be accomplish using the last visual studio framework 4.5